# OpenCV will not install due to libgtk2.0-dev dependencies

Tags: gtk, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 10.10 to use it with python.

The problem that I am facing is related to installing gtk2.0-dev.

I always get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.25.8) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried to do everything what I found on the web to overcome the problem. I even tried to use Synaptic Manager where I found libgtk2.0-dev, but it gives me an error on the dependencies too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me in a chroot.  You'll want to make sure your apt sources are up to date.

> sudo apt-get update

or alternatively, just use synaptic to update them.