# Unable to insall libgtk2.0-dev on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, opencv

I am using opencv 3 on ubunut 12.04 and while displaying an image the error message asks me to build the library with libgtk2.0-dev. I tried **sudo apt-get** **install libgtk2.0-dev** but I get the following error.

```
teraflops@teraflops-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-devReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
teraflops@teraflops-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

I have almost tried all the online solutions like [here 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111976/opencv-will-not-install-due-to-libgtk2-0-dev-dependencies) and [here 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248390/cant-install-several-development-libraries) with no results. Please suggest me any means to solve the problem. I have tried installing the **libpango1-dev** and **libcairo2-dev** separately but both have broken dependencies leading to **libfontconfig1-dev**. Trying to install the later gives

```
teraflops@teraflops-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1) but 2.10.1-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any kind of suggestion/solution is most welcome

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install -f` show, after you try to install libgtk2.0-dev?

Comment: Try this link: [OpenCV installation for Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.raben.com/book/export/html/3).

Comment: please post the output of  `apt-cache policy libfontconfig1`

Comment: Can you force it to install the required version of libfontconfig? `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1=2.8.0` It should be in the precise repository. Or you can download and install it with `sudo dpkg -i /PATH/TO/FILE.deb` from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libfontconfig1).

Comment: Sometimes this happens because the package you need is a 32 bits version. Try to install that.

Comment: Did you tested my solution? this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple issue -

`libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1) but 2.10.1-0ubuntu3 is to be installed`

You have libfontconfig1 2.10.1-0ubuntu3 from 12.10 installed but are on 12.04. So you'd need to replace that package with the 12.04 version & any other 12.10 package(s) you have installed that could cause conflicts. So good luck there...

`apt-cache policy libfontconfig1` & or `apt-cache madison libfontconfig1` should show this clearly

Answer (score 2):

Try installing all of them at the same time, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libpango1-dev libcairo2-dev libfontconfig1-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the package dependencies are related to packages out of x86_64 architecture. Try these following steps:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

I hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

That line from the output you received (when trying to install libgtk2.0-dev) seems to indicate you need to fix broken and missing packages.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

Then, assuming that was successful, you should be able to run the install command for libgtk2.0-dev without any problems

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

If it still doesn't work, try looking for what packages are being held back:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

If that command gives you any output (should be package names of whatever packages are being held) try this:

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

Then try to install libgtk2.0-dev again.

If it still fails, perhaps consider doing a dist-upgrade

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me on Rasbian Stretch while trying to install OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

## Download this files to 32 bits:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/gir1.2-gtk-2.0_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/libatk1.0-dev_2.4.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/libcairo2-dev_1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev_2.26.1-1_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-dev_2.32.1-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-0_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-common_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpango1.0-dev_1.30.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcomposite/libxcomposite-dev_0.4.3-2build1_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdamage/libxdamage-dev_1.1.3-2build1_i386.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pkg-config/pkg-config_0.26-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

## Or download this files to 64 bit:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-dev_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/gir1.2-gtk-2.0_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/libatk1.0-dev_2.4.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/libcairo2-dev_1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev_2.26.1-1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-dev_2.32.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-0_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-common_2.24.10-0ubuntu6_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpango1.0-dev_1.30.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcomposite/libxcomposite-dev_0.4.3-2build1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdamage/libxdamage-dev_1.1.3-2build1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pkg-config/pkg-config_0.26-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

## Install them with the command:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i *.deb
```

Executed in the download directory

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to install Wireshark 1.7.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04 - wireshark requires `libgtk2.0-dev`.

Everything is stuck because of the package `libfontconfig1-dev`:

1. Add the precise-updates deb server in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` . For France:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

2. Refresh `aptitude`:

```
apt-get update
```

4. Now you can install the broken package

```
apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
```

5. Put all problematic packages on the same command line. Here:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on 16.04 and the reason (for me at least) was that libcairo2-dev required on a specific version of libcairo-gobject2 and I had a newer one:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (= 1.14.6-1) but 1.15.2-0intel1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So the fix was:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo-gobject2=1.14.6-1
```

Which then allowed me to install libgtk2.0-dev

The real proper fix is for the maintainers of libcairo2-dev/libcairo-gobject2 to properly fix their dependency is that one can use later version of libcairo2-gobject2.